Do I still need to set my server's time zone to UTC?
OS is Raspberry Pi OS 12.
It looks like timedatectl shows the date both in UTC and my local timezone. Since it looks like the OS keeps track of UTC explicitly, is there any reason to not set the timezone to where the server is physically located? In the past I've always seen the advice "always use UTC for servers" but since timedatectl seems to keep track of UTC, perhaps this advice is now outdated.
I did find this post also: Should I (still) use UTC for all my servers? but didn't see timedatectl mentioned.

I'll trump your proverb ("always set servers to UTC") with "Don't lie to computers". Setting a correct local timezone makes System Admin easier (run the midnight cron job at "midnight", not UTC-midnight). The system's RTC (if you have one) is kept in UTC, and your timezone specifies the offset (and influences Daylight Saving Time/Standard Time switch).

Does your RasPi do something so important that not having unambiguous log timestamps in two specific hours each year (i.e. at daylight saving time changes) could be a problem to you?
Or do you think it reasonable that you would someday want to compare logs with someone located in a different time zone?
If the answer is yes to either of the above questions, then that would be a clear reason to set the server's default system timezone to UTC.
Note that you can always set the TZ environment variable to whatever you like in your own login sessions: that way, you could easily get interactive programs using local wall-clock time, but system daemons using UTC. This is something Unix-like systems have been able to do at least since the 1980's: it is nothing new.
Otherwise, feel free to do what is most convenient to you. If you want to "act like the big-time IT professionals", feel free use UTC. If local time is more convenient, use that.
As long as you set the timezone correctly, the system will still know the correct UTC time and automatically use it with email headers and similar technical contexts. Log timestamps increasingly tend to include the timezone specifier or the UTC offset value, either of which can be used to disambiguate the timestamps generated during Daylight Saving Time shifts if necessary.
(And if you can customize the log timestamp format, remember to include the timezone/UTC offset indicator in some form if you create logs in local time for the sake of convenience - it can be more important than you think.)
